# Where to find Advanced Python Field Calculator qgis syntax documentation

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, documentation

I am trying to follow some tutorials using Advanced Python field calculator, but when I enter the formula `value = $geom.area() / < area>` I get syntax error as in picture, while if I substitute the field name in pointy brackets with a number (eg. 1000) it works fine.

I have already checked the link http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9867 but still cannot find any documentation on the tool syntax

[image]

Comment: I would try using double quotes or no escape characters at all.

Comment: I afraid it still doesn't work for me: with quotes (both single and double) I get error _unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'_ , and with no escape character I get error _name 'area' is not defined_ . In general, it would be good to know where to find syntax documentation if any available

Comment: A number of articles point to a [Russian website](http://gis-lab.info/qa/fieldpyculator.html) (which can be translated using Google) with a tutorial on how to use the _FieldPyculator_ plugin, the knowledge can be transferred to the _Advanced Python Field Calculator_. Other than that, there's not much else I could find.

Comment: Thanks, I used the FieldPyculator to test my syntax. I am afraid it was a very sill error: field name should be capitalized as in the original file, so correct syntax was simply `value = $geom.area() / <AREA>`. Also the link is a good source of information.